# Pyattck | Use a File or Variable to Query Att&ck FW

Tags: python

This may end up being super silly but I'm using the Pyattck API to interact with the Mitre framework. It seems simple enough and what I need is very simple.
I have a list of Mitre Enterprise Technique IDs (maybe 40 or so) and I need to turn them into Tactic IDs and Tactic Names. The below code is a demonstration of doing that with the data that's already there and I get the results I want, for the most part, but I want to know how do I do this with my file or a variable (or even hardcoding the list)??

I've looked all through the documentation and there is nothing there or on the internet explaining how to do this. I take it as being a simple thing that my inexperience in coding is causing me to fail miserably on. I appreciate the help.

```html
from pyattck import Attck

attack = Attck()

for technique in tactic.techniques:
    print(technique.id)
    print(technique.name)
    for tactic in technique.tactics:
        print(tactic.id)
        print(tactic.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the configurations. Please look at
https://github.com/swimlane/pyattck
in configuration section. You can give your file path and read the file from the path and then do your stuff.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).